# All Android devices not recognized

Tags: android, driver, adb, adt, usb-debugging

I know that there is a lot of posts about this but none of which i saw helped me.
I got a new computer with windows 7 pro (64 bit) and i downloaded the eclipse-adt.
I have checked that the google `usb_driver` was installed.
I plugged in my devices (I'm using a galaxy nexus and a nexus 7) and non of them were recognized. (used to command `adb devices`).
To try and fix this, I Did:

1. Opened the Device manager from the control panel
2. Located my galaxy nexus device under "Other devices" (did the same with nexus 7)
3. Clicked "Browse my computer for driver software"
4. Gave the path to the google usb drives in the sdk. In my case the path was `C:\Dev\Android\eclipse-adt\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

I got the following message:
"Windows was unable to install your Galaxy Nexus. Windows could not find driver software for your device."
Any Ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: You could try to use a VM (or a partition) with Linux

Comment: @greywolf82 - Thanks but lets say that for now, Linux is not an option.

Comment: @MrT. Glad to help! I'll delete my comment and post it as an answer for future references to this question. Don't forget to accept it. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried [universal driver](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/adb-fb-apx-driver-universal-naked-t2513339)?

I'm using it for my Nexus 4 and it's working perfectly.